# Bottom Bar title not displayed proper using "com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1" library

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui

This is My Bottom bar [image]

I am Using **com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1** library

**Now the issue is that,**

Some Title of Bottom Bar is not displayed completely.

like.. ***Add product***, ***Notification*** .

i had tried too much but no result found for it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: decrease the size of text

Comment: how ??  com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1 lib have any method for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Grantland's AutoFitTextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) library which resizes the text to fit it's bounds.

Comment: Try adding this to styles.xml. This could single handedly fix your issue without the use of the library. 
<style name="BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed" parent="BB_BottomBarItem">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>

Comment: how to use it with Bottom bar that's the main issue.  after add your code into style.xml how to use  it. ???

Comment: add this style as your `bottomBar`'s style using the xml `style = @style/BB_BottomBarItem_Fixed` attribute